# Automation of UPDATE of column-level statistics on Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-synapse

I am planning to automate the refresh (i.e., UPDATE) of column level statistics on my Azure SQL Data Warehouse databases.  I plan to log the operations in a site-specific table and then dynamically generate SQL to refresh the statistics using the following approach:

1. DATE columns refreshed daily,
2. ID/code primary/foreign-key columns refreshed bi-weekly,
3. Indicator/boolean columns refreshed monthly, and
4. QTY/AMT (fact) columns refreshed quarterly.

I reviewed the STATS_DATE function at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190330.aspx, but this function does not appear to support the detail necessary for column-level statistics.  For example the output for one of my tables that has three columns which had statistics collected shows NULL for STATS_DATE:

```
SELECT 
  s.object_id,
  s.name,
  s.stats_id,
  s.user_created,
  STATS_DATE(object_id, stats_id) AS statistics_date  
FROM sys.stats s 
where object_id = 107141;
```

Returns

```
  object_id         name                   stats_id user_created statistics_date
 107,141            MySchema_MyTable_Col1         2         1          [NULL]
 107,141            MySchema_MyTable_Col2         3         1          [NULL]
 107,141            MySchema_MyTable_Col3         4         1          [NULL]
```

Did I overlook or misunderstand this function and should I be able to use STATS_DATE to manage my columns' statistics?

Following is a more complete demonstration:

```
 --Create a columnar demonstration table
 create table My_Schema.steve_test_table_columnar (c1_c integer, c2_c smallint,   c3_c date, c4_c decimal(18,2) ) ; 
--Create a heap demonstration table
create table My_Schema.steve_test_table_heap (c1_h integer, c2_h smallint, c3_h date, c4_h decimal(18,2) ) with (HEAP) ;

-CREATE STATISTICS statements:
CREATE STATISTICS My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR_C1_C ON My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR ( C1_C ) ;
CREATE STATISTICS My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR_C2_C ON My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR ( C2_C ) ;
CREATE STATISTICS My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR_C3_C ON My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR ( C3_C ) ;
CREATE STATISTICS My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR_C4_C ON My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR ( C4_C ) ;
CREATE STATISTICS My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP_C1_H ON My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP ( C1_H ) ;
CREATE STATISTICS My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP_C2_H ON My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP ( C2_H ) ;
CREATE STATISTICS My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP_C3_H ON My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP ( C3_H ) ;
CREATE STATISTICS My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP_C4_H ON My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP ( C4_H ) ;

--UPDATE (aka "REFRESH") STATISTICS statements:
UPDATE STATISTICS My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR ( My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR_C3_C ) ;
UPDATE STATISTICS My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP ( My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP_C3_H ) ;
UPDATE STATISTICS My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR ( My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR_C2_C ) ;
UPDATE STATISTICS My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP ( My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP_C2_H ) ;
UPDATE STATISTICS My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR ( My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR_C1_C ) ;
UPDATE STATISTICS My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR ( My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR_C1_C ) ;
UPDATE STATISTICS My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP ( My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP_C1_H ) ;
UPDATE STATISTICS My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR ( My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR_C4_C ) ;
UPDATE STATISTICS My_Schema.STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP ( My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP_C4_H ) ;

--Validation Steps

select s.[schema_id] , s.[name] from sys.[schemas] s where s.[name] = 'My_Schema';

--Results:
schema_id name
24        My_Schema

--Get Table Object ID
select t.[object_id] , t.[name] from sys.[tables] t 
inner join sys.[schemas] s 
on t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
where s.[name] = 'My_Schema' and t.[name]  in ('STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP' , 'STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR');

--Results:
object_id   name
516,196,889 steve_test_table_columnar
532,196,946 steve_test_table_heap


--Get Columnd IDs
select t.[object_id] , c.[column_id], t.[name] , c.[name] as Column_Name 
from 
     sys.[tables] t 
inner join 
     sys.[schemas] s 
on 
     t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
INNER JOIN
     sys.[columns] c
ON
     t.[object_id]       = c.[object_id]
where 
     s.[name] = 'My_Schema' 
 and t.[name]  in ('STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP' , 'STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR')

--Results:
object_id   column_id   name                       Column_Name
516,196,889 1           steve_test_table_columnar   c1_c
516,196,889 2           steve_test_table_columnar   c2_c
516,196,889 3           steve_test_table_columnar   c3_c
516,196,889 4           steve_test_table_columnar   c4_c
532,196,946 1           steve_test_table_heap       c1_h
532,196,946 2           steve_test_table_heap       c2_h
532,196,946 3           steve_test_table_heap       c3_h
532,196,946 4           steve_test_table_heap       c4_h

--Final review of statistics metadata
select t.[object_id] , c.[column_id], t.[name] as table_name
, c.[name] as Column_Name  ,st.stats_id , st.name   as Stats_Name  
,stc.stats_column_id 
,STATS_DATE(st.object_id, st.stats_id) AS statistics_date
from  
     sys.[tables] t 
inner join 
     sys.[schemas] s 
on 
     t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id] 
INNER JOIN
     sys.[columns] c
ON
     t.[object_id]       = c.[object_id]
INNER JOIN
     sys.stats st
ON
     st.[object_id]      = t.[object_id]
 and user_created = 1
INNER JOIN
  sys.[stats_columns] stc
on
     st.stats_id = stc.stats_id
 and st.[object_id] = stc.[object_id]
 and c.[column_id] = stc.[column_id]
where 
     s.[name] = 'My_Schema' 
 and t.[name]  in ('STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP' , 'STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR')
 ;



object_id   column_id   table_name                  Column_Name stats_id    Stats_Name                                  stats_column_id statistics_date
516,196,889 1           steve_test_table_columnar   c1_c         2             My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR_C1_C 1               [NULL]
516,196,889 2           steve_test_table_columnar   c2_c         3             My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR_C2_C 1               [NULL]
516,196,889 3           steve_test_table_columnar   c3_c         4             My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR_C3_C 1               [NULL]
516,196,889 4           steve_test_table_columnar   c4_c         5             My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_COLUMNAR_C4_C 1               [NULL]
532,196,946 1           steve_test_table_heap       c1_h         2             My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP_C1_H     1               [NULL]
532,196,946 2           steve_test_table_heap       c2_h         3             My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP_C2_H     1               [NULL]
532,196,946 3           steve_test_table_heap       c3_h         4             My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP_C3_H     1               [NULL]
532,196,946 4           steve_test_table_heap       c4_h         5             My_Schema_STEVE_TEST_TABLE_HEAP_C4_H     1               [NULL]
```

Comment: Hey Steve, I performed a create + update stats on my table and queried the stats table with the same query as in this question and it worked as expected. Has this been a reproducible issue?

Comment: I updated the OP with more detail.

Comment: Did these tables still stay NULL after you inserted data? Stats on empty tables return NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed that if the tables are loaded, the return value of STATS_DATE(id,id) is not null.  My experiment had involved only creating the tables.